# Trouble while loading an ontology with Pellet API

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, pellet

I want to use `Jena Pellet API` as `Reasoner` for infering new data in an **owl file**. I've downloaded the jar file **pellet.jar** and I've attached It to my Eclipse java project. However I'm still getting this error message while running my projet.

Can someone know what I missed here ?

here is my code

```
public class Mainprogram {

    public static String FILENAME = "file:./sample.owl";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Mainprogram().run();
    }

    protected OntModel getSoctraceOntology(){

        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);

        model.read(FILENAME, null, "RDF/XML");          

        // validation report
        ValidityReport report = model.validate();

        printIterator(report.getReports(), "Validation Rresults");          

        return model;

    }       
}
```

and here is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/clarkparsia/pellet/rules/ContinuousRulesStrategy
at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.OWLReasoner.<init>(OWLReasoner.java:90)
at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletInfGraph.<init>(PelletInfGraph.java:146)
at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasoner.bind(PelletReasoner.java:78)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.generateGraph(OntModelImpl.java:2744)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:139)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:128)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ModelFactory.java:410)
at soctrace.Mainprogram.getSoctraceOntology(Mainprogram.java:72)
at soctrace.Mainprogram.run(Mainprogram.java:39)
at soctrace.Mainprogram.main(Mainprogram.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 10 more
```

Thanks for any Help.

**Edition**

i'm using the `pellet-1.3.zip` file downloaded from [mindswap.org](http://www.mindswap.org/2003/pellet/download.shtml) and the `pellet.core.jar` file downloaded from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpelletcorejar.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please provide more details?

What is the Pellet version you are using? Did you check the examples those have given as part of pellet source code distribution? There are some examples for Jena also.

Apart from that, ContinuousRulesStrategy is part of com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules package. Please check if all the required jars are attached or not.

Comment: I've put more details in the question.

Comment: Pellet latest version is pellet-2.3.0.zip (Aug 22, 2011) and URL for downloading source code - [link](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet). I think you can use the latest version unless there is a reason.